# How to improve Time To First Byte for PHP, MySQL Application?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Every enough memory cache included in mysql. Initially page loads 20ms for TTFB after filtering a JQgrid table it takes 20s for TTFB. How to optimize this ? PLease anyone suggest what to do

Comment: If your JQgrid filtering uses database queries you should start there and optimize the queries by trying to run explains on them

Comment: You can analyze queries by prepending 'explain' keyword on them: 
explain SELECT ... What you are interested in there are the indexes and "extra" column

Comment: give more explanation. e.g, the example you've tried.

Comment: That should give you the idea which searches or filters are taking up the time, and there you can optimize them by adding indexes or re structuring your queries on the parts that take time

Comment: Show us the `SELECT` that is taking most of the time.  Also `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Adding a composite index is often the solution, but we need more info to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have indexes on all the WHERE and AND statements? This improves speed alot for my websites and I am using about 100 queries a visitor x 1000.